# Entity Framework .Net Core 3.1 - Code First vs Scaffolding

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

What I'm trying to do is implementing the model in Code First for this basic entities:

```
public class CompanyType{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string CompanyType {get;set;}
}

public class Company{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public string idCompanyType {get;set;} //Related 1-1 to CompanyType 
}

public class Employee{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public int idCompany {get;set;}  // --> Here I have to relate idCompany with CompanyId ( 1 company , N Employee
}
```

Questions are:

1. What is the correct way to implement the relations in Code First ?
2. Since the database of the application I have to realize will be very big, Can be a good approach designing the database in SqlServer and then proceed to scaffold the tables ?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CompanyType{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string CompanyType {get;set;}
}

public class Company{

    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public int CompanyTypeID
    public virtual CompanyType CompanyType {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CompanyID {get;set;}
    public virtual Company Company {get;set;}     
}

public class SomeContext : DbContext {
    public SomeContext() : base("SomeContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<CompanyType> CompanyTypeSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> CompanySet { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

This is basically how to set up your relations in EF code first

**Summary**

1. Create Data Model
2. Create Database Context
3. Setup EF
4. Code first Migration

you can find notes on step 3 and 4 here 
[Get Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

for the second part of your question you can refer to these links to weigh your options

[what is advantage of CodeFirst over Database First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556399/what-is-advantage-of-codefirst-over-database-first)

[EF Code-First Approach Vs Database-First Approach](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/ef-codefirst-approach-vs-database-first-approach)

[3 reasons to use code first design](https://www.itworld.com/article/2700195/3-reasons-to-use-code-first-design-with-entity-framework.html)

Comment: Thanks Francisco, really appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

As far as my point of view , should be dependant on a person, how he/she is comfortable. If you are good at SQL side, design db first then scaffold. If you are good at c# side, use code first approach

Comment: To implement relations, use fluent so you can add migrations. Have a look at this: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations. And Fluent API, refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties

Comment: Thanks Richards, if you are practice, can you show me by code how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) No comment as I never use it.

2) Database-First approach is the most effective to do. Save alot of your time. Yes, design tables in SQL Server, then run Scaffold-DbContext.